# Xcode, IOS, OBJECTIVE C

Tags: xcode

WOuld it be Ok to delete the Archives folders content from Xcode Library/Developer/Xcode….I am running out of DiskSpace and I just found out this takes about 12GB OF MY HDD, I AM USING XCODE 5.1.1

Comment: I dont think any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however if you have released binaries (i.e. binaries distributed via app store or locally within your enterprise) within these archives then you will lose your symbols and be unable to symbolicate crash logs.

If you haven't released binaries then there is no problem.

Side Note: I move all those Xcode folders to my `~/tmp` directory for easy access so examining/deleting their content is easy; and some of them, like `DerivedData`, can even be mapped to a RAM disk ;-)